# Как включить отзывы для товаров Woocommerce через MySql

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

В карточке товара Woocommerce на вкладке "Дополнительно" есть возможность включить отзывы, отметив соответствующий чекбокс.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня более 100 товаров, для которых нужно отметить этот чекбокс. Это будет очень долго и нудно.

Возможно нужно сделать MySql запрос к базе, чтобы это было быстрей?

Подскажите, кто сталкивался..

Answer (score 2):

Держите SQL запрос:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET comment_status = 'closed'  
     WHERE `post_type` = 'product'
```

> comment_status = 'closed'

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> comment_status = 'open'

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Лучше воспользоваться каким-нибудь [плагином для массового редактирования](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=woocommerce%20bulk%20edit)  или же через экспорт-импорт через csv.